# How can I use tabs to filter index page in active admin

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, activeadmin

I have filter as select drop down which is working fine but I want to use filter as tabs just like image attached how can I do this[image] any thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution these are the scopes being used just. My solution is

```
scope("New Jobs") do |jobs|
  jobs.where('"isCompleted" = ? OR "isCompleted" is NULL', false).order('created_at desc')
end
scope("Completed Jobs") { |scope| scope.where(isCompleted: true).order('updated_at desc') }
scope("Closed Jobs") { |scope| scope.where(is_closed: true).order('updated_at desc') }
scope("Exported Jobs") { |scope| scope.where(is_exported: true).order('updated_at desc') }
scope("Unassigned Jobs") { |scope| scope.where(subcontractor_id: nil).order('updated_at desc') }
scope ("On Hold Jobs") { |scope| scope.where(is_closed: true).where(task_user_status_SHLD: true)}
```